# refreshing a <div> with ajax but passing along a counter variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have two `.php` files. The first one `ajax_testing.php` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
    $index_local=1;
    $_SESSION['global_index'] = $index_local;
?>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="main">Who is batman? click count=<?echo $_SESSION['global_index'] ?>
        <button id="detailed">LINK</button>
    </div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { /// Wait till page is loaded
        $("button").click(function(){

            <?php 
                $_SESSION['global_index']+=1;
            ?>
            $('#main').load('property-detailed.php?global_index='
                + <?php echo $_SESSION['global_index']; ?>
                + ' #main', function() {});
        });
    }); //// End of Wait till page is loaded
</script>
</html>
```

Document number two is called `property-detailed.php` and looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php
    $_SESSION['global_index'] = $_GET['global_index'];
?>

<head>
<script></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="main">Who is batman? click count=<?php echo $_SESSION['global_index']; ?>
        <button id="detailed">LINK</button>
    </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { /// Wait til page is loaded
        $("button").click(function(){

            <?php
                $_SESSION['global_index']+=1;
            ?>
            $('#main').load('property-detailed.php?global_index='
                + <?echo $_SESSION['global_index'] ?>
                + ' #main', function() {});
        });
    }); //// End of Wait till page is loaded
</script>
</html>
```

I load the first page, and it has a variable, `$global_index`, that is set to 1 and a button with an ajax command to reload the `div` with the new information found on the second page.

My goal is to have the variable `$global_index` carry over and increment each time I press the button.  Is this possible with only ajax being implemented? If so, is there a way to make it happen with only the first page? Otherwise would it just be easier to have my database keep track of this number and increment that?

Comment: What the heck is that $_SESSION doing in the middle of your javascript ?

Comment: You need to use AJAX to update the `global_index` as well, plugging it in the middle of the Javascript code won't work.

Comment: Jeezez, now I get it, you thing the session variable will actually increment when you click the button, but unfortunately the PHP has long since been executed on the serverside and knows nothing about what your clientside javascript is up to, so that will never work. You need ajax or something else where you pass values to the server from the client.

Comment: If you send your variable with a GET, POST or whatever, you can access it in JS somewhat like this: `var something=<?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;`

Comment: Yeah @adeneo I was trying all sorts of stuff to get this to work, so I wouldn't be surprised if I was doing some really stupid stuff. This is my first stab at ajax. thanks for the feedback however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ajax_testing.php`:

```
   <?php session_start(); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <?php
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
    $count = $_SESSION['counter'];


    ?>
    <div id="main">Batman<?php echo $count; ?></div>
    <button id="detailed">Link</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click','#detailed',function(){
                var count = "<?php echo $count; ?>",
                    dataString = "counter=" + count;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "property-detaild.php",
                    data:dataString,
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#main').html(data);
                        console.log(data);
                    }

                });
            })

        });
    </script>
```

And in your `property-detailed.php`:

```
  <?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['counter'] = $_SESSION['counter']+1;
   echo $_SESSION['counter'];
  ?>
```

Comment: this isn't completely what I was looking for. As your script for ajax_testing.php works by posting data. it doesn't continually increase $index_local each time I click the button. am I missing something?

Comment: This works for the first button click but not any after,  I think your code @leonard-drapeza data: {index_local:1} just sets index_local to 1 each time. I can't seem to pass JUST index_local.

Comment: Try adding input field in your `ajax_testing.php`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this. Do you mean ajax_testing.php?index_local=X?